# VB YouTube Player API in WebBrowser Contorol doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vb.net, youtube

VisualStudio2010 Express & .net framework 4

In VisualBasic

I want to watch youTube on a Form.
So I used WebBrowser Control and YouTube Player API.
Video was able to play.
But functions that have been registered doesn't work.

Please help me.

YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="iframe_player_api" style="margin:10px"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var iframePlayerApiScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        iframePlayerApiScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, iframePlayerApiScriptTag);

        var player;
        function onReadyFnc(){alert('call onReadyFnc');}
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('iframe_player_api', {
            width: videoWidth,
            height: videoHeight,
            videoId: youtubeVideoID,
            playerVars: {},
            events: {
              'onReady': onReadyFnc //←Doesn't work!
              }
            });
          }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```